# Image is not loaded in IE and firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add CAPTCHA source to the div id `captchaImage`. But it is not working in IE and Firefox, but it is work in Chrome.
Please help me.
Difficulty reading the words? Load another image.

function getNewImage(){document.LogonForm.captcha.value = '';var url = '${startpage.captchaURL}';document.captchaImage.src = url;}

Thanks

Comment: "Not working" means the image is not loaded? Try `document.getElementById('captchaImage').src = ...` instead.

Comment: Please describe both the incorrect behaviour and the expected behaviour. Just saying 'it doesn't work' is the sign of a bad programmer.

Comment: you cant change the src of a img and expect the browser to render the new one, it isnt the right way to do.

Comment: @adeneo bad practice, it is recommended to remove and add a new one

Answer (score 0):

Like @Felix Kling wrote in the comments, use `document.getElementById('captchaImage')` because Firefox doesn't expose element IDs as properties of the document object.